# Listener c++ function usage

Tags: c++, listener

I am working with code that currently implements a listener class. I want to use the results of 2 of the functions from the listener class for more processing.

The 2 functions I have implemented and want to use are the following:

```
void Simulator::NetworkDecisionReceived(class::nss::SimulatorData* data, int decision) {
std::cout << "Simulator::NetworkDecisionReceived" << std::endl;
}

void Simulator::NetworkFinishedWithData(class::nss::SimulatorData* data) {
std::cout << "Simulator::NetworkFinishedWithData" << std::endl;
}
```

The listener is set in my member function like so:

```
network_data->SetListener(this);
```

Currently when I run the program the two functions are executed and print but I don't know how to say something like

```
if (NetworkDecisionReceived && NetworkFinishedWithData)
  do something
```

Comment: Add a couple of member variables to `Simulator` to store the state in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change functions to return value like this.

```
bool Simulator::NetworkDecisionReceived(class::nss::SimulatorData* data, int decision){
    std::cout<<"Simulator::NetworkDecisionReceived"<<std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

Then in the calling function you could check return value like:

```
if(NetworkDecisionReceived && NetworkFinishedWithData)
    // do something
```

Comment: Okay and then say if those functions are true then do my processing?

Comment: Yes. Then you can say